# Writing a matlab program for combinations of large numbers

Tags: matlab, combinations

Because for combinations of large numbers at times matlab replies `NaN`, the assignment is to write a program to compute combinations of `200 objects taken 90 at a time`.  Once this works we are to make it into a function `y = comb(n,k`).

This is what I have so far based on an example we were given of the probability that 2 people in a class have the same birthday.

This is the example:

```
nMax     = 70; %maximum number of people in classroom
nArray   = 1:nMax;
prevPnot = 1; %initialize probability
for iN = 1:nMax
    Pnot     = prevPnot*(365-iN+1)/365; %probability that no birthdays are the same
    P(iN)    = 1-Pnot; %probability that at least two birthdays are the same
    prevPnot = Pnot;
end
plot(nArray, P, '.-')
xlabel('nb. of people')
ylabel('prob. that at least two have same birthday')
grid on
```

At this point I'm having trouble because I'm more familiar with java.  This is what I have so far, and it isn't coming out at all.

```
k = 90;
n = 200;
nArray = 1:k;
prevPnot = 1;
for counter = 1:k
Pnot = (n-counter+1)/(prevPnot*(n-k-counter+1);
P(iN) = Pnot;
prevPnot = Pnot;
end
```

The point of the loop I wrote is to separate out each term 
i.e. `n/k*(n-k)`, times `(n-counter)/(k-counter)*(n-k-counter)`, and so forth.
I'm also not entirely sure how to save a loop as a function in matlab.

Comment: can't you use the `factorial` function of matlab first to see if you get the answer right, then replace that by your own factorial function.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the number of combinations of `n` objects taken `k` at a time, you can use [`gammaln`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html) to compute the logarithm of the factorials in order to avoid overflow:

```
result = exp(gammaln(n+1)-gammaln(k+1)-gammaln(n-k+1));
```

Another approach is to remove terms that will cancel and then compute the result:

```
result = prod((n-k+1:n)./(1:k));
```